# wildcard Subdomain only working index.php file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I m using wildcard directory to multiple subdomains, but only `index.php` works correctly. For example:

```
*. example.com/index.php
```

Other files content showing as `index.php`.

For example if I go to `*.example.com/style.css` then `index.php` content is showing. Why does this happen?

Here's my `.htacess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ])$ index.php?siteName=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?siteName=%1
```

Comment: Because this: `(.*)` will capture any URI and rewrite it to index.php. If you want to exclude files that actually exist from the rewrite rule, add this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`. Right now your two rewrite rules overlap and it doesn't make much sense to execute them both, perhaps you should include exactly what you are trying to accomplish in your question.